# Command getting null in my Attached property used for converting Event to command

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am using mvvm so i am trying to have less (or possibly no) code in code behind.
I want to convert KeyDown event on a TextBox to Command.I am using Interactivity dll
my Xaml code is:

```
  <TextBox Background="White" Name="txtHigh" AcceptsReturn="False" Height="23" Width="98"  Margin="3" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding SelectionHigh, Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource formatCell}}">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
                            <commands:EventToCommand Command="{Binding  HighValueChangedCmd}" ></commands:EventToCommand>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

and the code for converting EventToCommand is:

```
  public class EventToCommand : TriggerAction<FrameworkElement>
{
    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(EventToCommand), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CommandParameter.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(EventToCommand), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        if (Command == null) return;
        if (Command is RoutedCommand)
        {
            var rc = Command as RoutedCommand;
            if (rc.CanExecute(CommandParameter, base.AssociatedObject))
            {
                rc.Execute(CommandParameter, base.AssociatedObject);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Command.CanExecute(CommandParameter))
                Command.Execute(CommandParameter);
        }
    }

}
```

problem is in my Invoke  method I am Getting Command=null..Am not getting why so?
and I want to excecute logic in ExecuteCommand method only if the pressed key in enter or tab.
In code behind we can do this by using KeyEventArgs.

```
               KeyEventArgs e;        
               if (e.Key == Key.Enter || e.Key == Key.Tab)
              //logic
```

how can I achieve this in ExecuteCommand method???

Comment: I removed tags from title, [should questions include tags in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: Silly question, but HighValueChangedCmd definitely exists in the DataContext? No typos?

Comment: Yes it is in Data context. Do you have any solution for this please paste

Comment: Copied and Pasted and working fine . the Command is not coming null and is as expected. Can you please show your Command Code

Comment: I don't think Problem is in  .cs file. its in your binding!! whatever given by Den in Binding of Xaml try it its correct.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try an alternative way, without implementing Interaction and EventToCommand.

```
<TextBox Background="White" Name="txtHigh" AcceptsReturn="False" Height="23" Width="98"  Margin="3" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding SelectionHigh, Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource formatCell}}">
 <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Enter"  Command="{Binding DataContext.HighValueChangedCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}" />
        <KeyBinding Key="Tab"  Command="{Binding DataContext.HighValueChangedCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}" />
 </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: HighValueChanged command is written in ViewModel bt control is not coming in the ViewModel???? so its not working...is my binding correct???

Comment: @NehaBalkawade  Just edited my answer try using RelativeSource in command binding, x:Type is a type of element with viewmodel that contains command (element that contains textbox)